# CORS issue: "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

**I'm working on a Vue.js/Nuxt.js project where I'm making API requests to 'https://app.arianlist.com'. However, I'm facing CORS issues, and I've received the following error message:**

*"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://app.arianlist.com/api/public/items/index/book' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."*

**My Proxy Server:**

```js
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

const apiProxy = createProxyMiddleware('/api', {
  target: 'https://app.arianlist.com',
  changeOrigin: true,
  pathRewrite: {
    '^/api': '',
  },
  onProxyRes: function (proxyRes, req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  },
});

app.use('/api', apiProxy);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Proxy server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message says:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at '`https://app.arianlist.com/api/public/items/index/book`'

So the **browser** is making an HTTP request **directly** to `https://app.arianlist.com/api/public/items/index/book` and is **not** using your proxy.

You need to change the browser-side code so it uses the URL of your proxy.

---

You should also note that if a [preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) is being made then there will be additional CORS headers required in the response (what they are will depend on why a preflight is requested and will be expressed in the request headers for the preflight OPTIONS request). `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` by itself will not be sufficient, and the wildcard value may be forbidden for it.

Comment: I don't understand what should i do exactly.

Comment: Find the code that makes a request to `https://app.arianlist.com/api/public/items/index/bookz` and change it to make a request to your proxy server's URL instead.